# How can i spawn random objects at a certain position

Tags: swift, image, random

I'm using swift 3. For my game, Iwant to spawn a random object out of an array of 10 objects.  All the objects are named: obs1, obs2, obs3, obs4,... obs10

When I type:

```
Obs1 = childNode(withName: "obs\(arc4random_uniform(10) + 1))
```

My game crashes.  Can someone help?

Comment: Take a deep breath, use your fingers to count the array elements (starting at zero) and compare the results with the used index returned by `childNode(withName: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using gameplaykit for random shuffling

```
import GameplayKit

myArray = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: myArray) as! [obs]
```

That would randomly shuffle your array of type obs so that taking the first element would always result in a random one.